# SQL not querying text data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to query a number and a string in table, but it's just not working. I know its a simple question, but Im still new to SQL and i just cant see what is wrong with my query.

Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE question_answer(
    sample_id VARCHAR(10),
    question_id INT,
    question VARCHAR(255),
    answer VARCHAR(20)
);
```

The data looks like this:

```
sample_id question_id answer
001       1           Yes
002       1           No
003       1           Yes
...
```

and my query:

```
SELECT sample_id, question_id, answer
FROM question_answer
WHERE question_id = 1 AND answer = 'Yes' 
;
```

I works fine when i ask for question_id, but the answer field is not working. Thanks!

Comment: Which DMBS system you are using?

Comment: right, sorry. mysql.

Comment: Your Select should return the 1st and the 3rd row of your example data. If not, there's something else...

Comment: Right, its not doing that. its printing the field names, but none of the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly, "Yes" is not what you think it is.  I would start by trying to get a match at all:

```
WHERE question_id = 1 AND answer LIKE '%Yes%'
```

If that doesn't work, then:

```
WHERE question_id = 1 AND answer LIKE '%Y%e%s%'
```

Once you've gotten a match, you can try to figure out what is wrong.  Here are three common problems:

- Trailing/Leading spaces
- Look-alike characters (such as zero and capital O)
- Hidden characters (generally from a non-ASCII character set)

MySQL, alas, does not have `regexp_replace()`.  If this is just a single character, you can find it.  For instance, if it is at the beginning of the string:

```
select @char := left(answer, 1)
from question_answer
where answer regexp '^[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]')
limit 1;
```

This will set `@char` to the value of the character.  You can use this in an `update` to remove such characters from the string.

Comment: Ah, i see. I didnt think of that. yes, that solved the issue. Is there a fast way to update the answer column to remove these trailing and leading spaces? thanks!

Comment: the "%Yes%" solution. there is a lagging space at the end of "yes".

Comment: @DaneKania I couldn't understand what's wrong with using trim such as `select trim(' Yes ')='Yes'` returns 1, i.e. true.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `trim` function to remove the trailing spaces for the string type column :

```
SELECT sample_id, question_id, answer
  FROM question_answer
 WHERE question_id = 1 AND trim(answer) = 'Yes' ;
```

Besides, against case-sensitivity issues you may use

```
 WHERE question_id = 1 AND lower(trim(answer))='yes'
```

Comment: @DaneKania are you sure the values in the table are initcapped as `Yes` or `No`?

Comment: yes, that is what i entered into the database, but ive also tried 'YES' and 'yes' and none work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting this:

```
sample_id  question_id  answer
```

Then, you may be putting your column names in quotes like this:

```
SELECT 'sample_id', 'question_id', 'answer'
FROM question_answer
WHERE question_id = 1 AND answer = 'Yes'
```

Whereas, you should be doing this:

```
SELECT sample_id, question_id, answer
FROM question_answer
WHERE question_id = 1 AND answer = 'Yes'
```

or this:

```
SELECT `sample_id`, `question_id`, `answer`
FROM `question_answer`
WHERE `question_id` = 1 AND `answer` = 'Yes'
```